# how to allow div box to be displayed inside screen (not truncated)

Tags: jquery, css, html, tooltip

flotchart.org) for a scatterplot graphic application, using jquery.

Under a plotover event I display a tooltip, displaying dynamically a  through a function that make:

```
$('<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>') 
  .css({
  top: absoluteY,
  left: absoluteX,
} ).appendTo("body");
```

btw, the CSS Id description in the CSS file is:

```
.tooltip {
  z-index:1000;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  margin:1em 0 3em;
  border:5px solid #6B6B6B;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;     
  opacity: 0.87
}
```

Can someone help me understanding if there is some CSS attribute I have to adjust to allow the tooltip box is displayed inside the screen ?
BTW, box dimension auto adjustment would be ok, truncation isn't.

Please see the screenshots here:

screenshot 1: [tooltip correctly displayed if inside the parent div](http://solyaris.altervista.org/debug/tooltipOK.jpg)

screenshot 2: [tooltip TRUNCATED when the point is near the screen (div?) right margin](http://solyaris.altervista.org/debug/tooltipERR.jpg)

Sorry for my CSS ignorance / many thanks!
giorgio

Answer (score 0):

try adding `z-index:1000;` to the tooltip css, this should allow the tooltip div to be 'on top of' anything else on your page.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: visible` for parent will resolve this issue

Comment: infortunately it doesn't resolve setting: `<body style="overflow:visible;">` . see effect: [link]http://solyaris.altervista.org/debug/tooltipERR2.jpg I previously set `overflow:hidden` in body beacuse I do not want SCROLLBARS in the screen graphic layout.